# REACT call (Post) to Api (Laravel) return error 500

Tags: reactjs, laravel, post, http-status-code-500

I am fairly new to web developing and i am currently practicing with laravel and react.

At the moment i have a problem with a api call (post) getting back an error 500.

Here is the php code:

Model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'id',
    'name',
    'address',
    'phone',
    'email'
```

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $customer = Customer::create($request->all());
    return response()->json($customer, 201);
}
```

Api route

```
Route::apiResource('customers', 'App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController');
```

Here is the js code:

service (customers.js)

```
  export async function addCustomer(customer) 
  {
    fetch( '/api/customers/', 
    {
      method:'post',
      headers: 
      {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(customer)
    })
    .then(response => 
    {
      console.log(response);
      return response.json();
    })
  }
```

component (CustomerForm.js)

```
const CustomerForm = ({customer, showForm}) => {
    [...]
    const handleSubmit = (e) => 
        {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        addCustomer(model)
        .then(i => {}, 
            error => 
              {
              console.log(error.message)
              })
        .catch(e => 
          {
          console.log(e)
          console.log(response)
          }); 
         }

    /**
     * render
     */
    return (
        [...]
    );
}

export default CustomerForm;
```

Here is the error:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/customers/ 500 (Internal Server Error)
_callee3$   @   app.js:6606
tryCatch    @   app.js:6524
(anonymous) @   app.js:6524
(anonymous) @   app.js:6524
asyncGeneratorStep  @   app.js:6526
_next   @   app.js:6528
(anonymous) @   app.js:6528
(anonymous) @   app.js:6528
_addCustomer    @   app.js:6625
addCustomer @   app.js:6594
handleSubmit    @   app.js:5704
onSubmit    @   app.js:5725
[...]
```

What I've done:

- The same call works fine with postman.
- There is the csrf-token in my html head.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Check with the console in browser. You might want to enable CORS from the backend

Comment: Hello Vizard, I tried but the problem still remain. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone will ever need an answer, I found it.

1. Be sure to configure correctly your authentication system!
   In my case I was using Laravel Sanctum system forgetting a few things.
   Here is the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#spa-authentication
2. Add the CSRF Token to the POST request!
   Here some info: [How to get Laravel CSRF-token for sending it through fetch post request in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64631092/how-to-get-laravel-csrf-token-for-sending-it-through-fetch-post-request-in-react)

Have a nice day, night or anything you like!